# pointer to an array, difference in 2D array and 1d array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I a **2D** array say **int a[2][3]**

when we call the function say    **add(a);**

we receive it  using a pointer to an array **void add(int(*p)[3])**

**BUT**

In **1D** array say  **int b[5]**

we store address of array in a simple pointer to an integer 
**int *p;**      **p=b;**

**my question is that** why don't we store b in a pointer to an array ex **int(*p)[5]=b;**

Answer (score 1):

An array name when used as a value will decay into value equal to the pointer to its first element, with that type. This means for:

```
int a[2][3];
```

The name `a` will decay to `&a[0]`, which has the type `int (*)[3]`. But, for:

```
int b[5];
```

The name `b` will decay to `&b[0]`, which has the type `int *`.

However, `&b` is a pointer to `b`, which means it has the type `int (*)[5]`. It so happens that for an array type, its address will compare equal to the address of its first element. But, `&b` has a different type from `&b[0]`.